# Computer shut off duiring build processing, now won't build because there a lot of missing dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

My computer shut off, while my ASP.NET application in Visual Studio was building.

I have to download a bunch of dependencies, otherwise it won't run.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the problem with downloading the dependencies?

Comment: Most of the dependencies I am being told are now missing, are ones I wasn't using in the first place.